# Sql query - Struggling to write/structure

Tags: sql

I work for a distribution centre in the uk and i've recently started using sql queries to access data directly from the db.

I've been tasked with writing a query that gives the total number of locations we have in each aisle (from table locn_hdr) and total number of locations emtpy in each of those aisles. I'vr managed to get all the info i need but by using twp seperate queries.  I'm struggling to combine them into the below headers

Aisle - count of locations - count of empty locations

The two queries i have are below

Count of locations

```
select AISLE, COUNT(AISLE)    
from LOCN_HDR LH    
where LH.LOCN_CLASS = 'A'    
and BAY >= '0030'    
AND BAY <= '0230'    
AND PICK_DETRM_ZONE LIKE 'HG%'    
AND LH.AISLE <= 'QA'    
group by aisle    
Order by aisle;
```

Count of empties

```
SELECT  aisle, COUNT(dsp_locn)    
FROM locn_hdr lh    
WHERE lh.locn_class = 'A'    
AND bay >= '0030'    
AND bay <= '0230'    
AND pick_detrm_zone LIKE 'HG%'    
AND lh.aisle <= 'QA'    
AND NOT EXISTS    
(SELECT 1    
    FROM wm_inventory wi    
    WHERE wi.location_id = lh.locn_id    
    AND wi.on_hand_qty > '0')    
GROUP BY aisle    
ORDER BY aisle;
```

Ideally indont just want the answer with the sql re written. I want to understand how i can do something similar myself in the future.

Thanks in advance guys! Sorry if I havent given enough info, go easy on me i'm new!

edit

Hi, thanks for the help first of all! It is appreciated. However, it isn't working as i need it. the column count(lh.aisle) is counting the number of empty locations rather than the total number of locations in the aisle. I had to change the sql slightly because i was getting error messages so i temporarily used

```
SELECT  lh.AISLE, COUNT(lh.AISLE), COUNT(wi.location_id) -- count(lh.aisle) gives me the total empty locatins. Count(wi.location_id) gives me nothing...
FROM    LOCN_HDR lh
LEFT OUTER JOIN wm_inventory wi ON wi.location_id = lh.locn_id AND wi.on_hand_qty > '0'
WHERE   lh.LOCN_CLASS = 'A'
AND     lh.BAY BETWEEN '0030' AND '0230'
AND     lh.PICK_DETRM_ZONE LIKE 'HG%'
AND     lh.AISLE <= 'QA'
AND     wi.location_id IS NULL -- where there is no matching record for lh.locn_id with a quantity > 0
GROUP BY lh.AISLE
ORDER BY lh.AISLE;
```

This has given me a count of the empty locations which is fantastic. But I don't have a count of the total number of locations (empty or not).

Any more ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks like `SQL Server`, but it would be helpful to add a tag to the question indicating *which* DB you are using.

Comment: @levelonehuman: that is actually pretty much standard SQL

Comment: Unrelated, but: You shouldn't compare strings and numbers like `wi.on_hand_qty > '0'` `'0'` is a string constant, not a number. `0` is a number

Comment: Hi, I use oracle SQL developer to access the DB.... I'm not sure what type of database it is though to be honest. It is Manhattan Warehouse Management Software that provides it all if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  lh.AISLE, COUNT(lh.AISLE), COUNT(wi.dsp_locn)
FROM    LOCN_HDR lh
LEFT OUTER JOIN wm_inventory wi ON wi.location_id = lh.locn_id AND wi.on_hand_qty > '0'
WHERE   lh.LOCN_CLASS = 'A'
AND     lh.BAY BETWEEN '0030' AND '0230'
AND     lh.PICK_DETRM_ZONE LIKE 'HG%'
AND     lh.AISLE <= 'QA'
AND     wi.ID IS NULL -- where there is no matching record for lh.locn_id with a quantity > 0
GROUP BY lh.AISLE
ORDER BY lh.AISLE;
```

Something similar to this should work, although I can't really test it without data. Your two queries are basically the same, with the notable exception of `AND NOT EXISTS (... FROM wm_inventory ...)`.

Basically, you can `LEFT OUTER JOIN` this table on `location_id` and `on_hand_qty`. `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will return null where there is no match (instead of excluding them).

This means that if you have a record in `LOCN_HDR` with `locn_id = 1`, and you also have a record in `wm_inventory` with `location_id = 1` but a quantity of `2`, you will receive a `NULL` for this record.

Combined with the `WHERE wi.ID IS NULL` (change to suit the column on the `wi` table), this replaces the `NOT EXISTS` clause in the second query.

You *may* run into an issue with selecting `COUNT(wi.dsp_locn)` due to the `GROUP BY`, but you should be able to add `GROUP BY lh.AISLE, wi.dsp_locn` - this will combine all entries that have **both** the same `lh.AISLE AND wi.dsp_locn`.

If you need any additional explanation, please let me know - I'd be happy to give it a shot.

Comment: Note: This answer assumes you're using `sql server` - if not, the syntax may not be valid.

Comment: There is nothing non-standard (or SQL Server specific) in your answer

Comment: Hi, I use oracle SQL developer to access the DB.... I'm not sure what type of database it is though to be honest. It is Manhattan Warehouse Management Software that provides it all if that helps?